# Crawler not producing any output

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Building my first web scraper. I'm simply trying to get a list of names and append them to a csv file. The scraper seems to work but not as intended. Output file only produces one name which is always the last name scraped. Its always a different name when I rerun the scraper. In this case the name written to the csv file was Ola Aina.

```
#Create the spider class
class premSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "premSpider"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        
        # Create a List of Urls with which we wish to scrape
        urls = ['https://www.premierleague.com/players']
        
        #Iterate through each url and send it to be parsed
        
        for url in urls:
            
            #yield kind of acts like return
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)
            
    def parse(self, response):
        
        #extract links to player pages
        plinks = response.xpath('//tr').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        
        #follow links to specific player pages
        for plink in plinks:
            
            yield response.follow(url = plink, callback = self.parse2)
            
    def parse2(self, response):
        
        plinks2 = response.xpath('//a[@href="stats"]').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        
        for link2 in plinks2:
            
            yield response.follow(url = link2, callback = self.parse3)
        
    def parse3(self, response):
        
        names= response.xpath('//div[@class="name t-colour"]/text()').extract()
        
        filepath = 'playerlinks.csv'
        
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines([name + '\n' for name in names])

process = CrawlerProcess()

process.crawl(premSpider)

process.start()
```

Comment: You are using the `w` mode while writing to the csv file, which will create a new file and removes all others. Try using `a` from append.

Comment: @Thymen Your suggestion worked. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Scrapy's own "FEEDS" export..

add this just below your spider name:

```
custom_settings = {'FEEDS':{'results1.csv':{'format':'csv'}}}"
```

And modify parse3 to read as below:

```
    def parse3(self, response):   
        names=response.xpath('.//div[@class="name t-colour"]/text()').get()
        yield {'names':names}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do I handle names being outputed with ascii symbols? For example I get Sergio AgÃ¼ero instead of Sergio Aguero.

Comment: FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'  (https://www.proxyrack.com/scrape-flippa-com-scrapy/)  I've not used it but may be your solution.